# react-native link cant work,when i run react-native link

Tags: react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJCyr.png)when I text `react-native link react-native-gesture-handler`, it show me :

> rnpm-install ERR! ERRPACKAGEJSON No package found. Are you sure this is a React Native project?

Package name not found in D:\egame_android\egame\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml

> Error: Package name not found in D:\egame_android\egame\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml
>       at Object.projectConfigAndroid [as projectConfig] (D:\egame_android\egame\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\core\android\index.js:46:11)
>       at Object.keys.forEach.key (D:\egame_android\egame\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\core\index.js:100:36)
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at Object.getProjectConfig (D:\egame_android\egame\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\core\index.js:99:28)
>       at Object.link [as func] (D:\egame_android\egame\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\link\link.js:121:22)
>       at Promise.resolve.then (D:\egame_android\egame\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\cliEntry.js:117:22)'

Comment: make sure you are runnning the `react-native link` command in the react-native project directory

Comment: I did run this command under the my project directory

Comment: you can see the file route in the image description

Answer (score 0):

First, run following command in your terminal :

`cd <your_project_name>`

then run your command `react-native link react-native-gesture-handler`.

Comment: you can see the file route in the image description